# Dependant Recycleviews in Kivy

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

My problem: I want two RecycleViews, the second (CultureSubView) dependant on what was clicked in the first (CultureView).
It could work to call the "update" function of the CultureSubView whenever something in the CultureView was clicked, but I do not know how to do that.

Since that would have to be done in either the SelectableLabel (which might require an extra SelectableLabel as the CultureView does not need extra functionality in it)
or in the CultureView in the kivy language stuff.

What I also tried was to find anything that could trigger an "on_press" in the CultureView to then update the CultureSubView, but I also did not find any options for that. The idea is commented out in the code.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, BooleanProperty
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.recycleboxlayout import RecycleBoxLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView


Builder.load_string('''
<ScreenCulture>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        Label:
            pos_hint: {"x": .45, "top": 1}
            text: "Testosterone"
            size_hint: .1, .1

        GridLayout:
            id: culture_layout
            rows: 1
            cols: 3
            padding: dp(10)
            spacing: dp(10)
            orientation: 'horizontal'

            CultureView:
                id: culture_list_view
                # on_press? culture_sub_view.update()

            CultureSubView:
                id: culture_sub_view
                name_selected: 
                    "Planet" if not culture_list_view.name_selected else culture_list_view.name_selected

            CultureLabel:
                id: culture_text
                name_selected: "NVM" if not culture_sub_view.name_selected else culture_sub_view.name_selected
                text_selected: "This is totally a test text" if not culture_sub_view.text_selected else culture_sub_view.text_selected


<CultureView>:
    viewclass: 'SelectableLabel'
    name_selected: ''

    SelectableRecycleBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical' 
        default_size: None, dp(32)
        default_size_hint: .6, None
        size_hint: 1, .9
        multiselect: False
        touch_multiselect: False


<CultureSubView>:
    viewclass: 'SelectableLabel'
    text_selected: ''
    name_selected: ''

    SelectableRecycleBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical' 
        default_size: None, dp(32)
        default_size_hint: .6, None
        size_hint: 1, .9
        multiselect: False
        touch_multiselect: False


<CultureLabel>:
    size_hint_y: .85
    Label:
        halign: 'left'
        valign: 'middle'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.texture_size[1]
        text_size: self.width, None
        text: root.text_selected


<SelectableLabel>:
    # Draw a background to indicate selection
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (.05, 0.5, .9, .8) if self.selected else (.5, .5, .5, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
''')


class SelectableRecycleBoxLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior,
                                 RecycleBoxLayout):
    pass


class SelectableLabel(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Label):
    ''' Add selection support to the Label '''
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''
        self.index = index
        return super(SelectableLabel, self).refresh_view_attrs(
            rv, index, data)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        ''' Add selection on touch down '''
        if super(SelectableLabel, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            return self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)

    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
        ''' Respond to the selection of items in the view. '''
        self.selected = is_selected
        if is_selected:
            print("selection changed to {0}".format(rv.data[index]))
            rv.name_selected = rv.data[index]['text']
        else:
            print("selection removed for {0}".format(rv.data[index]))


class CultureView(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CultureView, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.data = [
            {"text": "Test1", "description": "testu"},
            {"text": "Test2", "description": "testo"}
        ]


class CultureSubView(RecycleView):
    planet_selected = StringProperty('')

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CultureSubView, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.selection_data = {
            '': [],
            'Test1': [
                {"text": "test1.1", "description": "test1"},
                {"text": "test1.2", "description": "text1"}
            ],
            'Test2': [
                {"text": "test2.1", "description": "text2"},
                {"text": "test2.2", "description": "test2"}
            ]
        }
        self.data = self.selection_data[self.planet_selected]

    def update(self):
        print("Updating")
        self.data = self.selection_data[self.planet_selected]
        self.refresh_from_data()


class CultureLabel(ScrollView):
    text_selected = StringProperty('')
    name_selected = StringProperty('')


class ScreenCulture(Screen):
    pass


screen_manager = ScreenManager()
screen_manager.add_widget(ScreenCulture(name="screen_culture"))

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return screen_manager


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

As always, thanks for your help :)

Comment: I have updated my post with invoking method *CultureSubView.update()* via kv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the item is *SelectableLabel*, use *on_touch_down* event to invoke the method *CultureSubView.update()*.

There are two options of invoking method *CultureSubView.update()*, one option is from kv file and the other is from Python script. Both options used Kivy ObjectProperty. Add *ObjectProperty* to hookup the *culture_sub_view*, *ScreenManager*, and *ScreenCulture*. Please refer to the example for details.

## Option 1 - Invoke *CultureSubView.update()* via kv file

In this option, the *on_touch_down* event is called twice because we have one class SelectableLabel and it is used in two places i.e. CultureView and CultureSubView.

### Snippets

#### kv file

```
Builder.load_string('''
<ScreenManagement>:
    screen_culture: screen_culture

    ScreenCulture:
        id: screen_culture
        name: 'screen_culture'

<ScreenCulture>:
    culture_sub_view: culture_sub_view

...

<SelectableLabel>:
    # Draw a background to indicate selection
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (.05, 0.5, .9, .8) if self.selected else (.5, .5, .5, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    on_touch_down:
        print('on_touch_down:')
        if self.selectable: \
            app.root.screen_culture.culture_sub_view.update(self.text)
```

#### Python Script

```
class SelectableLabel(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Label):
    ...

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        ''' Add selection on touch down '''
        if super(SelectableLabel, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            return self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)
...

class ScreenCulture(Screen):
    culture_sub_view = ObjectProperty(None)


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    screen_culture = ObjectProperty(None)


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ScreenManagement()
```

## Option 2 - Invoke *CultureSubView.update()* via Python Script

In this option, we invoke the method using *App.get_running_app().root.screen_culture.culture_sub_view.update()* and pass *self.text* to it.

### Snippets

#### kv file

```
Builder.load_string('''
<ScreenManagement>:
    screen_culture: screen_culture

    ScreenCulture:
        id: screen_culture
        name: 'screen_culture'

<ScreenCulture>:
    culture_sub_view: culture_sub_view
```

#### Python Script

```
class SelectableLabel(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Label):
    ...

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        ''' Add selection on touch down '''
        if super(SelectableLabel, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            App.get_running_app().root.screen_culture.culture_sub_view.update(self.text)
            return self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)
...

class ScreenCulture(Screen):
    culture_sub_view = ObjectProperty(None)


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    screen_culture = ObjectProperty(None)


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ScreenManagement()
```

## Example

### Option 1 - Invoke *CultureSubView.update()* via kv file

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, BooleanProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.recycleboxlayout import RecycleBoxLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView

Builder.load_string('''
<ScreenManagement>:
    screen_culture: screen_culture

    ScreenCulture:
        id: screen_culture
        name: 'screen_culture'

<ScreenCulture>:
    culture_sub_view: culture_sub_view

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        Label:
            pos_hint: {"x": .45, "top": 1}
            text: "Testosterone"
            size_hint: .1, .1

        GridLayout:
            id: culture_layout
            rows: 1
            cols: 3
            padding: dp(10)
            spacing: dp(10)
            orientation: 'horizontal'

            CultureView:
                id: culture_list_view

            CultureSubView:
                id: culture_sub_view
                name_selected: 
                    "Planet" if not culture_list_view.name_selected else culture_list_view.name_selected

            CultureLabel:
                id: culture_text
                name_selected: 
                    "NVM" if not culture_sub_view.name_selected else culture_sub_view.name_selected

                text_selected: 
                    "This is totally a test text" if not culture_sub_view.text_selected else culture_sub_view.text_selected


<CultureView>:
    viewclass: 'SelectableLabel'
    name_selected: ''

    SelectableRecycleBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical' 
        default_size: None, dp(32)
        default_size_hint: .6, None
        size_hint: 1, .9
        multiselect: False
        touch_multiselect: False


<CultureSubView>:
    viewclass: 'SelectableLabel'
    text_selected: ''
    name_selected: ''

    SelectableRecycleBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical' 
        default_size: None, dp(32)
        default_size_hint: .6, None
        size_hint: 1, .9
        multiselect: False
        touch_multiselect: False


<CultureLabel>:
    size_hint_y: .85
    Label:
        halign: 'left'
        valign: 'middle'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.texture_size[1]
        text_size: self.width, None
        text: root.text_selected


<SelectableLabel>:
    # Draw a background to indicate selection
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (.05, 0.5, .9, .8) if self.selected else (.5, .5, .5, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    on_touch_down:
        print('on_touch_down:')
        if self.selectable: \
            app.root.screen_culture.culture_sub_view.update(self.text)
''')


class SelectableRecycleBoxLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior,
                                 RecycleBoxLayout):
    pass


class SelectableLabel(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Label):
    ''' Add selection support to the Label '''
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''
        self.index = index
        return super(SelectableLabel, self).refresh_view_attrs(
            rv, index, data)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        ''' Add selection on touch down '''
        if super(SelectableLabel, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            return self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)

    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
        ''' Respond to the selection of items in the view. '''
        self.selected = is_selected
        if is_selected:
            print("selection changed to {0}".format(rv.data[index]))
            rv.name_selected = rv.data[index]['text']
        else:
            print("selection removed for {0}".format(rv.data[index]))


class CultureView(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CultureView, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.data = [
            {"text": "Test1", "description": "testu"},
            {"text": "Test2", "description": "testo"}
        ]


class CultureSubView(RecycleView):
    planet_selected = StringProperty('')

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CultureSubView, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.selection_data = {
            '': [],
            'Test1': [
                {"text": "test1.1", "description": "test1"},
                {"text": "test1.2", "description": "text1"}
            ],
            'Test2': [
                {"text": "test2.1", "description": "text2"},
                {"text": "test2.2", "description": "test2"}
            ]
        }
        self.data = self.selection_data[self.planet_selected]

    def update(self, name_selected):
        print("Updating")
        self.planet_selected = name_selected
        self.data = self.selection_data[self.planet_selected]
        self.refresh_from_data()


class CultureLabel(ScrollView):
    text_selected = StringProperty('')
    name_selected = StringProperty('')


class ScreenCulture(Screen):
    culture_sub_view = ObjectProperty(None)


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    screen_culture = ObjectProperty(None)


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ScreenManagement()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

### Option 2 - Invoke *CultureSubView.update()* via Python Script

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, BooleanProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.behaviors import FocusBehavior
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.recycleboxlayout import RecycleBoxLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.recycleview.layout import LayoutSelectionBehavior
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView


Builder.load_string('''
<ScreenManagement>:
    screen_culture: screen_culture

    ScreenCulture:
        id: screen_culture
        name: 'screen_culture'

<ScreenCulture>:
    culture_sub_view: culture_sub_view

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        Label:
            pos_hint: {"x": .45, "top": 1}
            text: "Testosterone"
            size_hint: .1, .1

        GridLayout:
            id: culture_layout
            rows: 1
            cols: 3
            padding: dp(10)
            spacing: dp(10)
            orientation: 'horizontal'

            CultureView:
                id: culture_list_view

            CultureSubView:
                id: culture_sub_view
                name_selected: 
                    "Planet" if not culture_list_view.name_selected else culture_list_view.name_selected

            CultureLabel:
                id: culture_text
                name_selected: 
                    "NVM" if not culture_sub_view.name_selected else culture_sub_view.name_selected

                text_selected: 
                    "This is totally a test text" if not culture_sub_view.text_selected else culture_sub_view.text_selected


<CultureView>:
    viewclass: 'SelectableLabel'
    name_selected: ''

    SelectableRecycleBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical' 
        default_size: None, dp(32)
        default_size_hint: .6, None
        size_hint: 1, .9
        multiselect: False
        touch_multiselect: False


<CultureSubView>:
    viewclass: 'SelectableLabel'
    text_selected: ''
    name_selected: ''

    SelectableRecycleBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical' 
        default_size: None, dp(32)
        default_size_hint: .6, None
        size_hint: 1, .9
        multiselect: False
        touch_multiselect: False


<CultureLabel>:
    size_hint_y: .85
    Label:
        halign: 'left'
        valign: 'middle'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.texture_size[1]
        text_size: self.width, None
        text: root.text_selected


<SelectableLabel>:
    # Draw a background to indicate selection
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (.05, 0.5, .9, .8) if self.selected else (.5, .5, .5, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
''')


class SelectableRecycleBoxLayout(FocusBehavior, LayoutSelectionBehavior,
                                 RecycleBoxLayout):
    pass


class SelectableLabel(RecycleDataViewBehavior, Label):
    ''' Add selection support to the Label '''
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''
        self.index = index
        return super(SelectableLabel, self).refresh_view_attrs(
            rv, index, data)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        ''' Add selection on touch down '''
        if super(SelectableLabel, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            App.get_running_app().root.screen_culture.culture_sub_view.update(self.text)
            return self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)

    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
        ''' Respond to the selection of items in the view. '''
        self.selected = is_selected
        if is_selected:
            print("selection changed to {0}".format(rv.data[index]))
            rv.name_selected = rv.data[index]['text']
        else:
            print("selection removed for {0}".format(rv.data[index]))


class CultureView(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CultureView, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.data = [
            {"text": "Test1", "description": "testu"},
            {"text": "Test2", "description": "testo"}
        ]


class CultureSubView(RecycleView):
    planet_selected = StringProperty('')

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CultureSubView, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.selection_data = {
            '': [],
            'Test1': [
                {"text": "test1.1", "description": "test1"},
                {"text": "test1.2", "description": "text1"}
            ],
            'Test2': [
                {"text": "test2.1", "description": "text2"},
                {"text": "test2.2", "description": "test2"}
            ]
        }
        self.data = self.selection_data[self.planet_selected]

    def update(self, name_selected):
        print("Updating")
        self.planet_selected = name_selected
        self.data = self.selection_data[self.planet_selected]
        self.refresh_from_data()


class CultureLabel(ScrollView):
    text_selected = StringProperty('')
    name_selected = StringProperty('')


class ScreenCulture(Screen):
    culture_sub_view = ObjectProperty(None)


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    screen_culture = ObjectProperty(None)


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ScreenManagement()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

## Output: Option 1 - Invoke *CultureSubView.update()* via kv file

[image: Img01 - Clicked on Test1]
[image: Img02 - Clicked on Test2]

## Output: Option 2 - Invoke *CultureSubView.update()* via Python Script

[image: Img03 - Clicked on Test1]
[image: Img04 - Clicked on Test2]

Comment: Thanks! This solved it :)
But I have a follow up problem: I want a text displayed when I click on the "first list" (Test1, Test2) which works the first time if I did not click anything on the second list (test1.1, test1.2). Do you know how to reset the SelectableLabel or call it via App.get_running_app() etc.?

Comment: Updated post with passing `self.text` to `update(self, name_selected)` method. Note: `planet_selected` is declared in class *CultureSubView* in main.py but in kv file, it is using `name_selected`.

Comment: I guess you could take out the planet_selected and just take name_selected then, mb ^^'